# bitlocker identifer not valid

Tags: bitlocker

I was given a new Windows 10 laptop at work and the initial setup required me to enable bitlocker and create a pin.  I was warned to make a recovery key so I did.  This was a file created by bitlocker with the recovery key and I stored it on another device.

During a technical support call with the laptop manufacturer I had to update the BIOS.  After this, I entered my bitlocker pin but it would not work.  I had to enter the recovery key saved earlier.  However, the recovery key is not valid.

On the recovery screen the identifier shown does not match the one in the recovery key file.
This is the only time I have used bitlocker.  I am positive this is the recovery key file generated when I setup bitlocker.

Is it possible the BIOS upgrade made a change in the way the identifier is calculated?

Is there any work-around for this?

Comment: The BIOS update can change TPM settings or invalidate the TPM altogether. I hope you had a TPM backup sent to AD DS. You are going to need to contact your AD administrator to unlock.

Answer (score 2):

The firmware update altered the hashes of the firmware ROM so the TPM refuses to unseal the encryption key. It can't affect the actual encrypted drive and its key is still the same.

Either the machine was reimaged/replaced sometime in the past without you noticing it (which caused the key to change obviously), or you mismatched the recovery key file (do you have multiple BitLocked drives by any chance?).

Now for the solution - computers that are part of an Active Directory domain save their BitLocker key to AD by default. You should ask your company's IT support. If the machine isn't part of a domain and you had a Microsoft Account configured on the machine, you could check whether you enabled the key backup by going to https://onedrive.live.com/recoverykey and by logging in with the same Microsoft Account you had on your computer.

Finally if none of the above works you can try downgrading your firmware to the same version you had when you enabled BitLocker - that should make the firmware hashes match again and hopefully the TPM will be happy to unseal the keys.

Comment: Is this common, that a simple BIOS update can effectively break Bitlocker? It's not always possible to revert a BIOS upgrade.